# rgbdslam v2 crashes after processing the first frame

Tags: navigation, ros-hydro, rgbd, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I have (supposedly) successfully catkin_make'd rgbdslam_v2  following the instructions from [here](http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/) on **ros-hydro** and **ubuntu 12.04**.
Then I run :

```
roslaunch rgbdslam rgbdslam.launch
```

and

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch (since I'm using the Kinect sensor)
```

Everything good so far (the gui, etc..). Then I press the "enter" button to record a single frame and after a couple of seconds I can see the registered cloud along with the features in the bottom-right window.
But, when I press the "enter" key again, to record a second frame I get the error below:

```
[ INFO] [1424181067.056503402]: Siftgpu Feature Descriptors size: 600 x 128
[ INFO] [1424181067.056629147]: Feature Count of Node:  600
[ INFO] [1424181067.066904524]: Odometry Delta: Translation 0 0 0
[ INFO] [1424181067.067152611]: Odometry Delta: Rotation 0 0 0 1
[ INFO] [1424181067.067285958]: No Valid Odometry, using identity
[ INFO] [1424181067.067507486]: Node ID's to compare with candidate for node 1. Sequential: 0
[ INFO] [1424181067.067683740]: Nodes to compare: 0
[ INFO] [1424181067.067813802]: Running node comparisons in parallel in 7 (of 8) available threads
[ INFO] [1424181067.078635881]: Depth and RGB image off more than 1/30sec: 36753459 (nsec)

rgbdslam: /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-opencv2-2.4.9-2precise-20140819-1745/modules/flann/include/opencv2/flann/kdtree_index.h:458: 
void cvflann::KDTreeIndex<Distance>::getNeighbors(cvflann::ResultSet<typename Distance::ResultType>&, const ElementType*, int, float) [with Distance = cvflann::L2<float>, typename Distance::ResultType = float, cvflann::KDTreeIndex<Distance>::ElementType = float]: Assertion `result.full()' failed.
================================================================================REQUIRED process [rgbdslam-2] has died!
process has died [pid 20933, exit code -6, cmd /home/kokirits/rgbdslam_hydro_ws/devel/lib/rgbdslam/rgbdslam __name:=rgbdslam __log:=/home/kokirits/.ros/log/e3d1a8d6-b6ab-11e4-9f21-4c80931194a0/rgbdslam-2.log].
log file: /home/kokirits/.ros/log/e3d1a8d6-b6ab-11e4-9f21-4c80931194a0/rgbdslam-2*.log

 Initiating shutdown!

================================================================================
[rgbdslam-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Anyone got an idea on how to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203282/rgbdslam-v2-crashes-after-processing-the-first-frame/) by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on ROS Answers with karma: 290 on 2015-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved, while browsing other answers.

I changed the entry in rgbslam.launch
from:

```
<param name="config/feature_detector_type"         value="SIFTGPU"/><!-- also available: SIFT, SURF, GFTT (good features to track), ORB. -->

<param name="config/feature_extractor_type"        value="SIFTGPU"/><!-- also available: SIFT, SURF, SURF128 (extended SURF), ORB. -->
```

to:

```
<param name="config/feature_detector_type"         value="ORB"/><!-- also available: SIFT, SURF, GFTT (good features to track), ORB. -->
<param name="config/feature_extractor_type"        value="ORB"/><!-- also available: SIFT, SURF, SURF128 (extended SURF), ORB. -->
```

SIFT and SURF work good as well, while GFTT produces another weird error.

---

Originally posted by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) with karma: 290 on 2015-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-27**:
hi kokiritis
I am in the same situation as you (turtlebot, hydro, rgbdslam, ubunto 12.04)
But when i run the rgbdslam there is no image the GUI is empty, but when i worked only with kinect it worked. i didn't found the solution;

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-27**:
can you please send to me the file launch and the steps that you did for the first time to run rgbdslam?

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-03-27**:
Hey sophye_turtlebot, by default rgbdslam v2 uses SIFTGPU as the feature detection and feature extraction method. What I did was just change those to ORB (SIFT and SURF) work as well. I can post my launch file when I get to my linux machine at the lab.

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-30**:
I stayed three days in the same problem:
in fact
here's what I did exactly: roslaunch rgbdslam openni+rgbdslam in a terminal

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-03-30**:
after to see errors with roswtf I found this warning:

- /camera/camera_nodelet_manager:

  - /tf_static
- /rgbdslam:

  - /tf_static
    any help plz